# @urql/svelte - Function called outside component initialization

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, urql

I'm trying to integrate graphQL API using @urql/svelte in svelte.
I have to call the graphQL query on the button click. But when I do that, I get following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function called outside component initialization
    at get_current_component (index.mjs:948:15)
    at getContext (index.mjs:981:12)
    at getClient (context.ts:7:14)
    at query (operations.ts:58:18)
    at getNonce (metamask.ts:27:2)
    at loadData (index.svelte? [sm]:28:17)
```

I have initialised connection in `__layout.svelte`.

```
    initClient({
        url: "http://localhost:8082/graphql",
        fetchOptions: {
            headers: {
                authorization: "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    });
```

Following is the `myquery.ts` file where query is defined:

```
import { operationStore, query } from '@urql/svelte';
const nonceQuery = `
   query ($address: String!) {
       nonceQuery(address: $address) {
           nonce
       }
   }
`;
export const getNonce  = (address: string) => {
    const nonce = operationStore(nonceQuery,
        { address }
    );
    query(nonce);
    return nonce;
};
```

And in `index.svelte` file I'm trying to call this on button click:

```
<script>
 import { getNonce } from "./myquery";
 let nonce;

 const onCall = () => {
   nonce = getNonce("some_address")
 }

 $: console.log("nonce: ", $nonce)
</script>

<button on:click={onCall}>
  Nonce
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace you can see that `getContext` was called at some point, which is [not allowed outside of the component initialization](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getcontext) as noted by the error message (though that message could mention that this is about `getContext`...).

You might need to rewrite the functions in a way that they no longer rely on getting a context internally. You could either pass the required object as an argument or possibly construct a sort of API class first, that gets the context during initialization but does not load any data yet.

Example:

```js
class Api {
    constructor() {
        this.client = getContext('client');
    }
    
    load() {
        // Use client here
        console.log(this.client);
    }
}

// Construct during component init, use later
const api = new Api();

function onButtonClick() {
    api.load();
}
```

[Extended REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e4f72935b1cc47f49989be8e8441f55a?version=3.47.0)

Comment: I moved `client: getContextClient()` from within a on:submit callback to `const client = getContextClient();` in the <script/> and that workedforme.